# Como implementar python decorators para reaproveitar código de uma função?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator-pattern

Pessoal estou tentando aprender sobre decorators pra ajuda automatizar alguns rotinas repetitivas.

Inicialmente, tenho várias funções que lêem arquivos e transformam cada linha deles em uma pyhton list dependendo de qual o conteúdo do arquivo, por exemplo:
Há o arquivo usuários contendo o username e nome completo:
jcalo-José Carlos
mxferr-Max Ferreira
... No final o resultado deve ser uma lista de tuplas [("jcalo", "José Carlos), ("mxferr", "Max Ferreira")]. Há também um arquivo com lista de produtos
produtos
pão
leite
Resultado esperado ["pão" , "leite"]

O procedimento comum é ler os arquivos e gerar a lista. Baseados nisto, já fiz o seguinte código, com o read_list com passos em comum na leitura de cada arquivo:

```
def read_list(funcao):
def warapper_function(*args, **kwargs)
if intens_delimiter == '\n':
lista = open("file", 'r').readlines()
else:
lista = open('file', r)
lista = list(servers).split(servers_delimiter)
lista.close()
lista = list(map(lambda x : x.strip(), servers))
lista = [x for x in servers if x != ""]
return lista
return warapper_function

@read_list
def read_produtos_list():
file = "produtos.txt"

@read_list
def read_users_list():
file = "usuários.txt"
```

Alguém sabe como eu continuo a escrita do código pra usar os decorators?
Meu objetivo é aproveitar o códio de ler o arquivo e gerar a lista e modificar as funções para obter o retorno correto de acordo com o tipo de arquivo a ser lido.

Comment: Esse problema não parece ser resolvido com decorador; você poderia simplesmente receber o nome do arquivo como parâmetro de uma função e assim reaproveitar o código. Os decoradores servem como uma espécie de Proxy na chamada da função decorada afim de alterar o seu comportamento. Não parece ser seu caso.

Comment: Entendi, eu pensei que pode adicionar uns if pra dependo dos parâmetros passados na função elas assuma comportamento diferentes. Valeu!

Comment: Recomendo-lhe fortemente que leia [este artigo](https://blogdolipe.com.br/how-to-use-decorators-in-python-ckdbiqgjg01h759s16hn95tlr) (que escrevi hoje mesmo, por coincidência), onde explico tudo o que precisa saber sobre decorators em Python